# Why does `class X: mypow = pow` work? What about `self`?

Tags: python, methods, self

This works and happily prints 81:

```
class X:
    mypow = pow

print(X().mypow(3, 4))
```

But why? Isn't the method given the extra "self" argument and should be utterly confused?

For comparison, I also tried it with my own `Pow` function:

```
def Pow(x, y, z=None):
    return x ** y

class Y:
    myPow = Pow

print(Pow(3, 4))
print(Y().myPow(3, 4))
```

The direct function call prints 81 and the method call crashes as expected, as it does get that extra instance argument:

```
Python 3:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Y' and 'int'
Python 2:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'instance' and 'int'
```

Why/how does Pythons own `pow` work here? [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) didn't help and I couldn't find the source.

Comment: Same way it gets passed to my `Pow`? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: That's because the `__self__` attribute of builtin functions is not writeable, hence it is always `None` for `pow`.

Comment: @vaultah Try in Python 2.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, I'm looking into `__self__` now, didn't know that yet.

Comment: [`__self__` on built-in functions is not as documented](https://bugs.python.org/issue14003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is connected to [method binding](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). Have a look at what Python tells you about these functions/methods:

```
>> pow
<built-in function pow>
>>> X.mypow
<built-in function pow>
>>> X().mypow
<built-in function pow>
```

and

```
>>> Pow
<function Pow at 0x7f88f5715f50>
>>> Y.myPow
<unbound method Y.Pow>
>>> Y().myPow
<bound method Y.Pow of <__main__.Y instance at 0x7f88f57117e8>>
```

Further the documentation states:

> Class dictionaries store methods as functions. In a class definition, methods are written using [`def`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#def) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda), the usual tools for creating functions. [...]
>
> To support method calls, functions include the [`__get__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound or unbound methods depending whether they are invoked from an object or a class. [...]

But built-in functions don't have a `__get__()` method. That's why `pow` wasn't bound and could be used the way you observed, while `Pow` couldn't.

Answer (score 5):

This is because python functions defined in C (builtins) have auto handled self argument. Here is pow function header :

`static PyObject *
math_pow(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)`
Here you can see that self is always passed by interpreter.

Comment: Isn't that `math.pow`, not `pow`?

Comment: It's math.pow, but behavior is same.

Comment: Hmm, I checked and confirm it does behave the same in that regard (i.e., happily returns 81.0). I found [the source of that](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L927) and it just ignores the `self` argument. I guess I'd need to know how user-defined methods *don't* ignore it to really understand it. AshwiniChaudhary also commented something about builtin's `__self__` not writable, which I confirmed, but I guess that shouldn't matter if it's not used anyway. I'll look a bit into both issues.

Comment: The problem is user defined methods behave different way when compared to C methods. Each python C method must have defined self, and it's filled always with something (current object, global etc.). User methods don't have that option, so that means when used way you have shown, first argument will be filled with self, but when used as usual, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @tynn has pointed the reason that `pow` does not have `__get__`, so it can not be transformed to `bound method`.

But why? The key thing behind all of these things is `descriptor protocol`. If anybody wants to understand Python better, then should go to understand `descriptor protocol`, which is not hard, but very simple and powerful.